# Trying to code a check answer for my coding quiz, but it isn't working properly, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, dom, events

Here's the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
function checkAnswer(questionIndex) {

// This ID goes to a div storing the four buttons
    var answersId = document.getElementById("answers");

//The four spans inside the buttons which has data-answer, targeting at their id. The id and data-answer are the same value.

    var answer0 = document.getElementById("option0").getAttribute("data-answer");
    var answer1 = document.getElementById("option1").getAttribute("data-answer");
    var answer2 = document.getElementById("option2").getAttribute("data-answer");
    var answer3 = document.getElementById("option3").getAttribute("data-answer");

    answersId.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        if (event.target.hasAttribute("data-answer")) {

            event.preventDefault;

            if (answer0 == questionList[questionIndex].correctAnswer) {
                console.log(answer0)
                score++;
                console.log(score)
                console.log("This is option0")

            }

            else if (answer1 == questionList[questionIndex].correctAnswer) {

                console.log(answer1)
                score++;
                console.log(score)
                console.log("This is option1")


            } else if (answer2 == questionList[questionIndex].correctAnswer) {

                console.log(answer2)
                score++;
                console.log(score)
                console.log("This is option2")

            } else if (answer3 == questionList[questionIndex].correctAnswer) {

                console.log(answer3)
                score++;
                console.log(score)
                console.log("This is option3")

            } else {

                console.log(score)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is sorta hard coded right now, but I want to make sure it actually works before optimizing it.

Basically, I have buttons for a multiple choice quiz, and the idea is that depending on the button clicked, they get a point for choosing the correct answer. In this case, the data-answer should match whatever the correct answer is. (If the correct answer is option1, then "option1" == "option1")

But no matter what button is clicked (in this case, the answer is indeed option1), it gives the point and gives the console.log for option 1, meaning that it constantly chooses that if statement even when I'm picking the other buttons.

It's just driving me crazy that the wrong answer, which is the else statement, isn't being recognized
or rather, it keeps recognizing the second if statement despite clicking the wrong answer. I think my logic is sound, it just isn't working right.

Do you know what I could be missing here?

Edit: Here's the questionList array being referenced, and the objects for each of those variables:

```
var question1 = {
    text: "Commonly used data types do NOT include:",
    choices: ["1 - Booleans", "2 - Alerts", "3 - Strings", "4 - Numbers"],
    correctAnswer: "option1",
};

var question2 = {

    text: "The condition of an if/else statement is enclosed within ______.",
    choices: ["1 - Quotes", "2 - Curly Brackets", "3 - Parentheses", "4 - Square Brackets"],
    correctAnswer: "option2",
};

var question3 = {
    text: "Arrays in Javascript can be used to store ______.",
    choices: ["1 - Numbers and strings", "2 - Other Arrays", "3 - Booleans", "4 - All of the above",],
    correctAnswer: "option3",
};

var question4 = {
    text: "String values must be enclosed within ______ when being assigned to variables.",
    choices: ["1 - Quotes", "2 - Curly Brackets", "3 - Commas", "4 - Parentheses"],
    correctAnswer: "option0",
};

var question5 = {
    text: "A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is:",
    choices: ["1 - Javascript", "2 - console.log", "3 - Terminal/bash", "4 - For loops"],
    correctAnswer: "option1",
};

var questionList = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5];
```

Edit 2:

Adding where I'm calling the function. This time I moved the eventlistener out of the checkAnswer() function and right before it is called.

```
document.getElementById("start-quiz").addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault;
    event.stopPropagation;

    countDown = 75;
    countDownSpan.textContent = countDown;
    document.querySelector("#description").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#start-quiz").style.display = "none";
    contentId.style.textAlign = "left";
    setTime();
    createAnswers();
    generateQA(0);

    var answersId = document.getElementById("answers");

    answersId.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        checkAnswer(0)

    });
});
```

Edit 3:

If it helps, here is the link to the github page:

https://github.com/WarriorofZarona/Coding-Quiz
GitHub

Comment: Edit the question and put your `questionList` definition.

Comment: I've added the questionList definition, along with the object definitions of each of those elements.

When you say edit my question, did you want me to rephrase the title question of my post?

Comment: I went ahead and added a question at the end of the title

Comment: You're calling `answersId.addEventListener("click", ...)` inside of your `checkAnswer` function. Did you mean to do that outside of the function?

Comment: I've had it both ways to test it out but it came with the same result, just that the last time I commited it, I left it inside.

Comment: @AndrewBautista, can you add an example of how you're calling your `checkAnswer` function?

Comment: Edited to show where I am calling the function

Comment: Maybe you have something like undefined==undefined . Have you logged your valued ?

Comment: Yeah, I put the console.logs in to test and make sure they're coming out correctly, and as far as I know, they are.

I also made another edit: added the github page if anyone wants to look at the complete code for more clarity

Comment: I see you've updated your code on github and solved your problem, right ?